# Scaling An R Image

Tags: image, r, scale

I'd like to scale an image in R for further analysis rather than for immediate plotting.

EBImage's resize() would be ideal for this if I could use EBImage, but I need to avoid it so I have to find an alternative.

I haven't had any luck searching. I could implement bilinear filtering by hand, but before I do that I'd like to confirm that there aren't any alternatives.

Comment: `rasterImage` can do interpolation, but probably only when actually rendered.

Answer (score 6):

[Nearest neighbour](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/) resizing is the most common and simplest to implement.

Assuming your image is one layer/channel, and thus one matrix:

```
resizePixels = function(im, w, h) {
  pixels = as.vector(im)
  # initial width/height
  w1 = nrow(im)
  h1 = ncol(im)
  # target width/height
  w2 = w
  h2 = h
  # Create empty vector
  temp = vector('numeric', w2*h2)
  # Compute ratios
  x_ratio = w1/w2
  y_ratio = h1/h2
  # Do resizing
  for (i in 0:(h2-1)) {
    for (j in 0:(w2-1)) {
      px = floor(j*x_ratio)
      py = floor(i*y_ratio)
      temp[(i*w2)+j] = pixels[(py*w1)+px]
    }
  }

  m = matrix(temp, h2, w2)
  return(m)
}
```

I'll let you figure out how to apply this to a RGB image

Heres a test run for the code above on the red channel of this image:

```
lena = readImage('~/Desktop/lena.jpg')[,,1]
display(lena)
```

[image]

```
r = resizePixels(lena, 150, 150)
display(r)
```

[image]

```
r2 = resizePixels(lena, 50, 50)
display(r2)
```

[image]

Note:

1. be careful, the target widths and heights must maintain the aspect ratio of the original image or it wont work
2. If you're trying to avoid `EBImage`, to read/write images try the package `jpeg` methods `readJPEG` and `writeJPEG`

Answer (score 3):

Nearest neighbour scaling (no interpolation) can be implemented quite easily.
While the answer by @by0 is clear, I'd like to offer an alternate implementation.
It works on the matrix representation of the image, which I find simpler than indexing into a vector.

```
resizeImage = function(im, w.out, h.out) {
  # function to resize an image 
  # im = input image, w.out = target width, h.out = target height
  # Bonus: this works with non-square image scaling.

  # initial width/height
  w.in = nrow(im)
  h.in = ncol(im)

  # Create empty matrix
  im.out = matrix(rep(0,w.out*h.out), nrow =w.out, ncol=h.out )

  # Compute ratios -- final number of indices is n.out, spaced over range of 1:n.in
  w_ratio = w.in/w.out
  h_ratio = h.in/h.out

  # Do resizing -- select appropriate indices
  im.out <- im[ floor(w_ratio* 1:w.out), floor(h_ratio* 1:h.out)]

  return(im.out)
}
```

This works with arbitrary image scalings, not just square. On the other hand, it will only preserve the aspect ratio of the image if `w.out/w.in = h.out/h.in`.

Comment: Can I do this for an array 3D? For example, from array(56,64,46) to array(256,256,256)? How? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I haven't looked at this code in a while. You will get a weirdly stretched 3D image because the ratios are different for the different directions (256 / 56 != 256 / 46, etc).

Comment: Thanks, works a lot better then the solution above. Weirdly I had to switch all col/row references to get it work correctly.